# Objective C Adding custom objects into NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, object, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

I want to store a list of data records in a NSMutableArray for use in a UITableView.  In other languages I would have used a simple 'type' structure to define the record structure but I understand the way to do this in Obj-C is to define a new class.  I've done this as follows :

```
@interface CustSuppListItem : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *acCode;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *acCompany;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *acContact;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) double osBalBase;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) unsigned int acAccStatus;
@end

@implementation CustSuppListItem
@synthesize acCode, acCompany, acContact, osBalBase, acAccStatus;
@end
```

In the viewDidLoad of my UITableViewController I instantiate the array :

```
tableListDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Once I have retrieved my data, I add it to the array as follows :

```
CustSuppListItem *custSuppItem = [[CustSuppListItem alloc] init];
[custSuppItem setAcCode:[jsonCustSuppRecord getStringForKey:@"acCode"]];
[custSuppItem setAcCompany:[jsonCustSuppRecord getStringForKey:@"acCompany"]];
[custSuppItem setAcContact:[jsonCustSuppRecord getStringForKey:@"acContact"]];
[custSuppItem setOsBalBase:[jsonCustSuppRecord getDoubleForKey:@"osBalBase"]];
[custSuppItem setAcAccStatus:[jsonCustSuppRecord getIntForKey:@"acAccStatus"]];                             
[tableListDataArray addObject:custSuppItem];                          
[custSuppItem release];
```

In my table cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I retrieve the data for the current cell as follows:

```
CustSuppListItem *listDataRecord = [tableListDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.lblCompanyName setText:listDataRecord.acCompany];  // EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
[cell.lblAcCodeContact setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",
                                listDataRecord.acCode, listDataRecord.acContact]];
[cell.lblBalance setText:[Utils fmtNumber:listDataRecord.osBalBase withDecPlaces:2]];
[cell.lblStatus setText:[Utils exchAccStatusDesc:listDataRecord.acAccStatus]];
return cell;
```

In the dealloc method for the view controller I release the NSMutableArray :

```
[tableListDataArray release];
```

I'm very new to Obj-C so it would be great if somebody could confirm everything I've done so far makes sense and is in order.  I am getting an intermittent EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when trying to read the acCompany property (see comment next to line) so something must not be right.

Any help appreciated,

Jonathan

Comment: did you retain the tableListDataArray in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Any other details from the console when you have the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error?  As an aside, the design (encapsulating the `CustSuppListItem` entity as a class) is very typical ObjC design.

Comment: @vpdn Why `retain`?  `init` returns an object with a `retainCount` of +1

Comment: @alanduncan tableListDataArray is created in viewDidLoad, then used in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Since he doesn't seem to use a property for it, I was just wondering whether he has manually retained the array in his viewDidLoad method.

Comment: I don't currently use a -retain option when instantiating the tableListDataArray, I didn't think I needed one?  The variable is declared in the header file :

    @interface CustSuppListView : UITableViewController
    {
        NSMutableArray *tableListDataArray;
    }

Comment: No, you shouldn't need a retain. Alan Duncan is correct. Did you have any luck with any of my suggestions below?

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for your help.  I'm still experimenting but I think my errors are down to how I reload the list when the user changes the search query.  I'm still getting used to handling this correctly but I think I need to do [tableListDataArray removeAllObjects] then [tableView reloadData] immediately before requerying, then another [tableView reloadData] when I've finished populating the array - would you agree?

Comment: That seems reasonable, though depending on how you want your app to behave I'm not sure that you'll need the first call to `reloadData`. Probably can't do any harm though! That said, I'm having trouble seeing how not emptying the array before repopulating would cause the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error you're reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your code looks reasonable and correct to me at first glance.

A few things that I would look at are:

1. Confirm that cell definitely has a property `lblCompanyName`. If you're trying to assign to a property that doesn't exist then you will get this type of error. Have you defined a custom cell object type?
2. Confirm that it is always the `acCompany` property that is causing the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, and not just any property on the object. One way to do this would be to change the ordering of the lines in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.
3. Confirm that the listDataRecord that's causing the crash is getting populated correctly in the first place. In other words, confirm that your `jsonCustSuppRecord` is always valid. What does `jsonCustSuppRecord getStringForKey:` return if the key doesn't exist in the `jsonCustSuppRecord`?
4. Set a breakpoint at this line: `[tableListDataArray addObject:custSuppItem];` and examine the contents of the `custSuppItem` each time (this is an extension of point 3. above)

Comment: @Jonathan - what was the problem/solution (so that others can learn from this)?